# Windows Phone 7 Development - Do I need a Service Provider

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

With the upcoming WP7 release, I am wanting to develop against the framework.  I have an iPhone and don't want to get away from using that service.  I know Visual Studio has tools to emulate the WP7 device for testing one's apps but this is not a true test.  I was wondering if it is possible to get a WP7 without a service, e.g. AT&T, and do development?

Are there many drawbacks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the net fine using wifi or connected to the pc via it's lan.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your question is but, you can get devices on Pay-As-You-Go tarrifs and network unlocked. What is available and how much it will cost will depend on which country you are in and who you buy it from.

Once you have an account with the marketplace, you can unlock any phone for development.
There are limits on the number of phones you can unlock though.